# Custom list of auto complete options in ios using monotouch

Tags: ios, autocomplete, xamarin.ios, autocorrect

I want to be able to supply my own list of available auto correct / auto complete options for a text input in an ios app created in monotouch.

The list of words is updated via a web service. Examples of this type of functionality can be seen in the Ebay app when completing a search.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to adapt this Objective-C solution: http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: Thanks! Using that site I was able to get something working, I put together a demo at http://www.lucasmoffitt.com/custom-autocomplete-in-monotouch