# Are there any libraries in iOS for identifying phonetically same sound

Tags: ios, search, phonetics

I am trying to build an iOS application. In one of the screens the user can type something in a search bar and I have to take same action for different spellings of the same word.

**For eg:** User can type *"elephant"* or *"alephant"* or *"elefant"*. I have to take same action for all these three words.

Is there any library that identifies these words as similar ones ? I cannot use spellchecker as I need this in languages other than english also ..
I did some research and I found that there are some phonetic algorithms like Text::soundex for achieving this on server side. Wondering if any libraries there for iOS ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: +1 because you explained your question well, but wow is this an obscure question. Good luck getting it answered!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if two NSStrings are similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984442/check-if-two-nsstrings-are-similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better alternative to Soundex would be Double Metaphone or, even better, Metaphone 3. You don't say what language you are using, but both of these algorithms are available in C++, C#, and Java

Answer (score 2):

There's no soundex available in for example `NSString`, but if that's what you want, it's fairly easy to implement. Here's a—albeit horribly formatted—[soundex NSString category](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSStringSoundex) from CocoaDev.

You could also use the Levenstein Distance algorithm to catch simple spelling errors. Also easy to implement (read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for the details), but [here's a NSString category](https://gist.github.com/1515464) for that.

Before you use these algorithms, normalize the input. There's the amazing `CFStringTransform` class in Core Foundation (see [this great article](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/) about it on NSHipster—especially the last part about normalization) that automatically can transform different language inputs into normalized forms.