# Getting differences between two NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, string-comparison

I've got two `NSString`s and I want to get the differences between them.

Let me make an example:

```
NSString *pippo = @"pippo";
NSString *pippone = @"pippone";
```

I would like to get the different characters in the two instances. How can I do that?

Comment: I started to type an answer to your question and then realized to give the best answer, one would need to know a bit more detail. For example, if string one is "meat" and the other one is "spicy meatball", do you want the difference to be "spicy ball" or the letters that are different between the sentences, e.g. {s,p,i,c,y,b,l}?

Comment: How do you define the difference between strings?  Is it always as you've expressed here, where one string has additional characters at the end?  Or, for example, how would you consider the difference between _pippo_ and _pissone_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if two NSStrings are similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984442/check-if-two-nsstrings-are-similar)

Answer (score 2):

Though several special cases (e.g. suffixes) can be handled with simpler algorithms, ro handle general case, you can :

1/ first extract a common sequence. Unless your string are very long, the longest common subsequence algorithm will be your choice (LCS, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

You can find an obj-c and swift implementation of LCS here : http://jakubturek.pl/blog/2015/06/27/using-swifts-string-type-with-care/

2/ from the LCS, it's easy to get the diffs, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility for instance.
See below an obj-C implementation (NSString category, assuming we have longestCommonSubsequence: from the above link) :

```
- (NSArray *) lcsDiff:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *lcs = [self longestCommonSubsequence:string];
    NSUInteger l1 = [self length];
    NSUInteger l2 = [string length];
    NSUInteger lc = [lcs length];
    NSUInteger idx1 = 0;
    NSUInteger idx2 = 0;
    NSUInteger idxc = 0;
    NSMutableString *s1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:l1];
    NSMutableString *s2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:l2];
    NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    for (;;) {
        if (idxc >= lc) break;
        unichar c1 = [self characterAtIndex:idx1];
        unichar c2 = [string characterAtIndex:idx2];
        unichar cc = [lcs characterAtIndex:idxc];
        if ((c1==cc) && (c2 == cc)) {
            if ([s1 length] || [s2 length]) {
                NSArray *e = @[ s1, s2];
                [res addObject:e];
                s1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:l1];
                s2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:l1];
            }
            idx1++; idx2++; idxc++;
            continue;
        }
        if (c1 != cc) {
            [s1 appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c1 length:1]];
            idx1++;
        }
        if (c2 != cc) {
            [s2 appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c2 length:1]];
            idx2++;
        }
    }
    if (idx1<l1) {
        [s1 appendString:[self substringFromIndex:idx1]];
    }
    if (idx2<l2) {
        [s2 appendString:[string substringFromIndex:idx2]];
    }
    if ([s1 length] || [s2 length]) {
        NSArray *e = @[ s1, s2];
        [res addObject:e];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Code will return an array with one element (string1,string2) for each difference between the two strings, e.g. 
[@"abcXefY" lcsDiff:@"aZbcKef"] will return `@[ @[ @"", @"Z"], @[ @"X", @"K"], @[ @"Y", @""]];`

Comment: Thanks! Works fine with Swift 2.2 version of Longest common subsequence from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Swift).
Nice example of Longest common substring in Objective-C can be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Objective-C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some regEx :

I made this function once to replace a string in another string by the string/pattern you want.

```
-(NSString *)replaceInString:(NSString *)chaine :(NSString *)pattern
             :(NSString *)template
{
NSMutableString *chaineMutable = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:chaine];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] init];

regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
             options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:(NSMutableString *)chaineMutable
             options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, [chaine length])
             withTemplate:template];

NSString *returnedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:chaineMutable];

return returnedString;
}
```

**Then you can call it :**

```
NSString *difference = [self replaceInString:pippone :pippo :@""];
```

So you will replace "pippo" found in "pippone" by "" (nothing) so the result will be "ne".

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is working if the difference char is at end or at start, but it is not giving diff char if it is in middle, for ex, if chaine=@"pippone" and pattern=@"pipone", then it is not able to give difference as :p is diff

Answer (score -3):

Updated Answer:

```
-(void)getDifferenceBetweenString:(NSString *)firstString secondString:(NSString *)secondString{
    NSString *longerString = @"";
    NSString *shorterString = @"";
    if (firstString.length >= secondString.length) {
        longerString = firstString;
        shorterString = secondString;
    }else{
        longerString = secondString;
        shorterString = firstString;

    }
    NSArray *shorterArray = [self convertToArray:shorterString];
    NSArray *longerArray = [self convertToArray:longerString];
    NSMutableArray *differenceLettersArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString * letter in shorterArray) {
        if (![longerString containsString:letter]) {
            if (![differenceLettersArray containsObject:letter]) {
                [differenceLettersArray addObject:letter];

            }
        }
    }


    for (NSString * letter in longerArray) {
        if (![shorterString containsString:letter]) {
            if (![differenceLettersArray containsObject:letter]) {
                [differenceLettersArray addObject:letter];

            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"differences = %@",differenceLettersArray);
}

- (NSArray *)convertToArray:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (i < string.length) {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:i];
        NSString *chStr = [string substringWithRange:range];
        [arr addObject:chStr];
        i += range.length;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
[self getDifferenceBetweenString:@"pippo" secondString:@"pippone"];
```