# How to get a % difference of two NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, foundation

I'm thinking this may be impossible to do resonably, but I figured I would take a shot at it. So lets say I have two `NSStrings`. One is `@"Singin' In The Rain"` and the other is `@"Singing In The Rain"`. These strings are very similar, but have a small difference. I'm trying to find a way where I could write something like the following:

```
NSString *stringOne = @"Singin' In The Rain";
NSString *stringTwo = @"Singing In The Rain";

float dif = [stringOne differenceFrom:stringTwo];
//dif = .9634 or something like that
```

One project that I did find similar to this was taken from the previous similar question on Stack Overflow: [Check if two NSStrings are similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984442/check-if-two-nsstrings-are-similar/12984609#12984609). However, this simply returns a BOOL which isn't as accurate as I need it to be. I also tried looking into the `compare:` documentation for `NSString` but it all looked too basic. Another similar thing I found is at https://gist.github.com/iloveitaly/1515464. However, this gives varying results, even saying two of the same string are different occasionally. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the difference?  You mean that 96.34% of the characters are the same?

Comment: The first thing you need to decide on is what makes a string different from another. What are the rules?

Comment: You could theoretically use 2 NSArrays, put each letter in the array and then compare element 1 on one array with element 1 of the other

Comment: Why would you put them in an array?

Comment: @logixologist: There's no need to put the characters into an array, just access the characters from the string directly with `characterAtIndex:` et al.

Comment: ok good point.. just brainstorming ;)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: Levenshtein distance?

Comment: You guys are making some great points about how to define the difference. I guess I need to take a step back and think about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm thinking that the Levenshtein distance is the closest thing to what I want. However, lets say I have two new `NSStrings` `@"iPhones and iPads"` and `@"iPhones & iPads"`. The distance is technically three, but in reality it should be one. Is there something to compensate for this? (I hope this isn't an entirely different question and if so, just let me know)

Comment: You should ask Google.

Comment: @user2844801 - Treat each word as a single symbol, then your "iPhones and iPads" and "iPhones & iPads" have a difference of 1. See my answer below for a suggestion along these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another off the wall suggestion:

The source, and hence the algorithm, for `diff` and similar programs is easily available. These compare input on a line-by-line basis and detect insertions, deletions and changes.

When comparing text strings for "closeness" then the insertion, deletion or changing of words seems as good a measure as any.

So:

1. Break each string into "words" (white space separated should be sufficient).
2. Compare the two lists using the `diff` algorithm, treating each "word" as a "line", use a re-sync length of 1 (the number of "lines" that need to be the same to treat the two inputs as back in sync)
3. Calculate the "closeness" as the number of insertions/deletions/changes compared to the total word count.

For the two example strings this would give 1:4 changes or 75% similar.

If you want greater granularity for each change split the two words into characters and repeat the algorithm giving you a fraction the word is similar by (as opposed to the whole word).

For the two example strings this would give 3 6/7 words out of 4, or 96% similar.

Comment: Conceptually, this is very similar to Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague, but I would assume that the most satisfactory results will come from using [`NSLinguisticTagger`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you parse each for tags with the `NSLinguisticTagSchemeLexicalClass` scheme then your string will be broken down into verbs, nouns, adjectives, etc. In your example, even if you weren't spotting that singin' and singing are the same, you'd spot the other three words are the same and that the thing at the end is a noun, so they're both about doing something in the same thing.

It'd probably be wise to use something like a [BK-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) to compare individual words where you suspect there may be a match (a noun obviously doesn't match an adverb but two nouns may match even if spellings differ).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend dynamic time warping for such comparisons:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

This will however return distance between two strings (so you'll get 0 for identical), but this the best starting point I can think of.